# How to enable auto-complete (intellisense) in Eclipse IDE for Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse 2019-09 and I’m working on a Java application using some Collection classes.

I needed to see all the available methods for the Map interface but when I pressed “Ctrl+Space”, auto-complete didn’t work. “No default proposals” message came up.

How can I enable IntelliSense for Java in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a workaround to fix this issue in the below article.

[Eclipse Java autocomplete not working](https://www.chrisnewland.com/solved-eclipse-java-autocomplete-not-working-259)

In Windows:

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced
```

In MacOSX:

```
Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced
```

Then, make sure the following options are ticked in both top (default content assist list) and bottom (Content Assist Cycling) sections.

```
Java Non-Type Proposals
Java Proposals
Java Type Proposals
```

[image]

[image]